# How the weight updation happen simultaneously for classification and regression in case of object detection?

Tags: python, object-detection, object-detection-api, faster-rcnn

If we see the faster rcnn network. we have the classification for prediction of class label and localization for prediciton of bounding boxes. How the weight updation happen simultaneously??
Does that depends on the loss function??

Comment: The network is trained end-to-end. However, this question is not on-topic for this website I believe.

Comment: Seems more a question for datascience